# Distributions with 'Gaussian Tails'

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

In a paper I was reading, the following seemingly artificial assumption is used:

suppose $f$ is some probability density function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $\phi$ denote the density of a $N(0,I_d)$ random variable. Then they assume either:

1. for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, there exists a finite positive constant (possibly depending on $f$ such that $f(x) \le C_f \phi(x)$.
2. for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, there exists finite positive constants $c_1,c_2$ (not depending on $f$) such that $c_1 \phi(x) \le f(x) \le c_2 \phi(x)$.

I am trying to understand what kind of densities belong to either class. For example, the standard sub-gaussian assumption does not belong to the class of densities in 1. since any unbounded density does not satisfy 1, even though there are sub-gaussian distributions that are unbounded.

Questions:

1. what kind of distributions belong to either class? Do gaussian mixtures belong to either class?
2. What does the dependence of the constants on $f$ change ? or how does the class of densities that satisfy either of the conditions change if the constants were/were not allowed to depend on $f$?

Comment: The dependence on f does not seem to make much sense, as f is fixed anyway throughout the assumption. That aside, I see this as a statement about Radon-Nikodym derivatives, which are assumed to be either (1) bounded above or (2) bounded above and away from zero. It is quite restrictive and will not be satisfied by a Gaussian mixture.

Comment: the paper discusses a set of density functions f such that 1. is satisfied for all densities in this class - so i think in this setting the constant allowing to vary with the density should make a difference? Regarding mixtures, I think arbitrary mixtures don't, but it seems that mixtures with bounded means might? Say you have a mixture of two gaussians with means $-a$ and $a$ for some constant a?

Comment: ok, so it is an assumption about a set of density functions, in which case allowing it to vary with f makes sense. Then, allowing it to depend on f is the same thing as applying the assumption separately to each density rather than using fixed constants for the whole set of them.

Comment: and a mixture of Gaussians will not work, because $\exp(-(x-a)^2/2)/\exp(-x^2/2)$ is unbounded for $a\not=0$.

Comment: I might be able to give an answer to 1. Super-Gaussians belong to the first class - these are measures of the form $e^{-|x|^a}$ with $a > 2$. They are sometimes compared with the Gaussian measure in the context of Markov semigroups. If $a = 2$ the associated process is called hypercontractive and if $a > 2$ then it is also ultracontractive. As for the second class, it seems to me by writing $f(x) = g(x)\phi(x)$ for some $g > 0$ that $f$ can only be a bounded below and above perturbation of $\phi$, that is $f = g\phi$ where $\inf g > 0$ and $\sup g < \infty$.

Comment: @pencilwriter that sounds interesting, is there a good ref for super-gaussians that you'd recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure of any specific references that treat them in detail, but there is a brief discussion of the gaussian type measures on pp2 of [a paper by Barthe, Cattiaux, Roberto](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407219.pdf) and a discussion in Theorem 8.1 and Remark 8.2 of [a book by Bobkov, Zegarlinski](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~bobko001/papers/2005_Memoirs_BZ.pdf) ultracontractivity of supergaussian measures. I think supergaussian measures appear earlier in the literature - there is [a result by Davies and Simon](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/173.pdf) from 1984 ...

Comment: that essentially says if you have a Schrodinger operator $-\Delta + V$ then you can conjugate by the ground state $\varphi_0 > 0$ and get a Markov operator which is symmetric in the Lebesgue space $L^2(\varphi_0^2dx)$. Since $\varphi_0$ is $L^2(dx)$-normalised you can think of $\varphi_0^2(x)$ as a density and if I recall correctly the result is that growth of $V$ at infinity translates into decay of tail estimates on $\varphi_0$. In particular if $V = |x|^a$ grows faster than quadratic (i.e. $a > 2$) then $\varphi_0^2$ has supergaussian tails.